# Redirection based on URL - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect

If someone types in 'www.morgancc.edu', I want it to redirect to our mobile site located at 'www.morgancc.edu/m' However, I only need to redirect with this *exact* URL. I don't want it to redirect if you go to something like 'www.morgancc.edu/programs', which is what it is currently doing.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location = "www.morgancc.edu") {
   window.location.href = 'http://www.morgancc.edu/m/'; 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location).hostname with an empty path is what you seem to want

```
if (window.location.hostname == "www.morgancc.edu" && 
    window.location.pathname=="" ) {
   window.location.href = 'http://www.morgancc.edu/m/'; 
}
```

Alternatively look at the href

```
if (window.location.href== "http://www.morgancc.edu") {
   window.location.href = 'http://www.morgancc.edu/m/'; 
}
```

You may need to add some / here or there

Comment: Makes sense for what I am doing. However, now it will not redirect at all.

Comment: Your second suggested worked!  This is the code I used:

'<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.href == "http://www.morgancc.edu/" ) {
   window.location.href = 'http://www.morgancc.edu/m/'; 
}
</script>'

Answer (score 9):

The equality operator is `==`, not `=`.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest on using a sever-side scripting language to redirect base on the device visiting your site. you also have a typo in your if statement, you should have **==** not **=**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location == "www.morgancc.edu") {
   window.location.href = 'http://www.morgancc.edu/m/'; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Using this code in my blogger site. Works perfectly.